# Set `top.location === location` in an mx:HTML's iframe (and read it's value cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, dom, air

I'm 99.99% sure this can't be done...

Lets say I've got an `<mx:HTML />` element in my Flex w/ Air 2.6 desktop application with its `src` set to `example.com`. This HTML element contains a single iframe whos `src` is `facebook.com`.

Now, facebook doesn't like to be framed. Essentially, it checks to see if its `document.location == top.location`

So, what I need to do is set `top = document;` (or `window`, whichever it may be) in the iframe. Oh, and `top` needs to remain equal to the iframe's `document` when the user navigates to another page/domain.

As a bonus i'd like to be able to read the current document's location from the Air application.

Anyone have an ideas if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executive summary: not possible.

There are security implications to what you're wanting to do here, which is why it's not allowed. As you've suggested in your comment to J_A_X, it's because of cross-domain issues and the security involved there.

If you're building a browser, I suggest you build the way the browser looks in the actual AIR app itself, rather than in nested iframes.

AFAIK, the only way to successfully build a browser completely in HTML/CSS/JS is going to be with a web proxy or a screen scraper, and that's opening up a brand new can of worms.

Comment: Thanks. If you add the word "No" in your answer I'll accept it.  :-)

Comment: Also, mozilla is working on "chromeless", its Firefox with no chrome. From what I've read, it looks like we'll be able to implement our own browser UI entirely with CSS, HTML, and JS.

Comment: @David: the chromeless stuff looks pretty nice. Looks like what you want to do, correct?

Comment: Yup. I'll likely have to wait a year or so for something to be considered stable/secure, I imagine. And by that time Chromium will probably have a chromeless clone (I wonder what they'll call it. hm) and I'd much rather go with that.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with that iframe?  Your method seems very hackish to me; either way, this is a javascript/html issue, not an issue with Air.

If you want to get the current location of the iframe, it's as easy as called a Javascript function within the html that's currently displayed in the HTML component like so:

```
htmlComponent.htmlLoader.window.someJSFunction();
```

I *think* this should be able to return you a string, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: Its a javascript issue alright. I was hoping it could be solved with AIR. You cannot get the current document.location of a frame cross-domain. You also cannot hide the fact that the iframe is an iframe from the iframe it self (wow, that was confusing).

Comment: To answer you question more directly: I've got an HTML/javascript/css based browser that loads websites in iframes. There are some obvious pitfalls like cross-domain issues with this method; I was hoping air would be able to help out.

Comment: Then why don't you just access the websites directly through the air html component instead of an iframe?

Comment: J_A_X, This is what I'm doing now (thanks for your help, BTW).